# How to fetch the data of particular date in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to fetch the data of particular date in mongoose?

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
  foods: [
    {
      food: { type: Object, required: true },
      quantity: { type: Number, required: true }
    }
  ],
 
  shopId:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  }

},{ timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });
```

I have tried the following but it does not work

```
const dat=new Date(2020,07,23);
  const ndat=new Date(2020,07,24);
  const sid=req.shop._id;
  Order.find({shopId:sid,created_at: {$gte: dat, $lt: ndat}})
  .then(data=>{
    res.send(data);
  })
```

I need to fetch the order details of particular date.

Comment: what is `dat` here ?

Comment: const dat=new Date(2020,07,23);

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a syntax error:

```
const dat=new Date(2020,07,23);
  const ndat=new Date(2020,07,24);
  const sid=req.shop._id;
  Order.find({shopId:sid,created_at: {"$gte": dat, "$lt": ndat}})
  .then(data=>{
    res.send(data);
  })
```

OR this also works

```
  const sid=req.shop._id;
  Order.find({shopId:sid,created_at: {"$gte": new Date(2020,07,23), "$lt": new Date(2020,07,24)}})
  .then(data=>{
    res.send(data);
  })
```

Comment: what's the erorr ?

Comment: i think new Date returns iso date which does not match with created_at

Comment: Agree with you,try changing the created_it.

Comment: Order.find({shopId:sid,created_at: {"$gte": new Date(2020,06,23), "$lt": new Date(2020,06,24)}}) this returns the data of 07 month bro

Comment: You mean data for a whole month(07)?

Comment: try removing 0 from month in `new Date(2020,06,23)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218492/discussion-between-dharani-shankar-and-pr1ax).

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores timestamps, not dates. Ensure the date you are passing is converted to timestamps that cover your order, and ensure that your order has the creation timestamp that you think it has.

Use mongo shell to find out what is actually stored in your database, and get the queries working in mongo shell first before trying to do them in your application.